# Cannot use dll in projects other than wpf applicaion

Tags: c#, dll, reference, skype4com

This is really strange. If I run this in a wpf application:

```
SKYPE4COMLib.Skype mySkype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
```

I get no errors.

I want to run that in a asp.net application. when I do run it there I get:
[image]

note that I don't get any build errors and the error arises at run-time. The SKYPE4COMLib.Skype class is provided by Skype and can be downloaded from [here](https://developer.skype.com/accessories/skype4com). I don't understand why I am able to instantiate an object from that class just if I am using a wpf appliation.

Things I have tried: (recall I want to use that library from my asp.net application)

1) Adding a wpf application to my solution. Then referencing that project from my asp application. I get the same error.

2) Tried to create a web service and instantiate the class in the web service. That does not work eather.

3) Change the target framework from .Net Framewrok 4 Client Profile to different ones. This solved the problem I was able to instantiate the class but then I am not able to call the methods.

**I am having a hard time understanding why I am able to instantiate an object from a class if I am in a wpf application but not in a .net application or even a console application!** I seems as if skype is trying to block that on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long hours of trying I decided I where going to make my wpf application a console application by adding the necessary references and classes. Then I compared and I noticed that if I added:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
```

to the main method it works!!!!!

as a result my main method now should look like:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{

    class Program
    {
        [System.STAThreadAttribute()]                
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SKYPE4COMLib.Skype oSkype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
        }
    }
}
```

on asp.net there is not a main method. well not one that I know of. so in asp.net I had to add the AspCompat attribute equal to true.

so my asp.net aspx pages now look like:

```
    <%@ Page AspCompat="true" Language="C#" .... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the user account in which your web service runs (aspnet) does not have sufficient privilege to do that?
Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa292118) and see if impersonation works for you.

Comment: I compile it then run it as an admin and it did not work. I guess i'll have to make my wpf application a .net one by adding the necessary refernces. Maybe when i'll do it will stop working!